"Ужасный код" является оскорблением?
Я уже 8 лет на Stack Overflow, оставил много комментариев и полезных ответов. В основном, пишу комментарии, так как развернутые ответы на многие вопросы сейчас давать нет смысла. Комментарии обычно либо содержат решение, либо подталкивают автора к нему через наводящие вопросы, либо указывают на проблемы в коде. Иногда добавляю аналитику: например, если вижу, что автор движется в неверном направлении, могу указать, что "это в корне неправильно", "код ужасен" или "так писать не стоит". По моему мнению, это не оскорбление, а честная оценка, чтобы автор понял, что подход стоит пересмотреть.
Часто после таких комментариев авторы задают уточняющие вопросы вроде "А что тут не так?" или "Почему код ужасен?", и я всегда готов помочь, разъяснить, а если надо — даже написать пример кода, лишь бы человек научился. Ведь мы все были новичками и писали не лучший код. Ох как бы я хотел, чтобы кто-то честно сказал: "Ты делаешь бред", — это сэкономило бы массу потраченного времени на ненужное, лишнее, неверное.
Теперь о проблеме. В течение восьми лет мои комментарии никого не трогали, но с появлением модератора aepot я заметил, что они начали исчезать.
Например, сегодня был задан вопрос с откровенно плохим, "ужасным" кодом. Видно, что это ученик, который пишет домашнее задание — калькулятор. Я открыл вопрос, изучил и написал такой комментарий (примерный текст по памяти):

Бедный учитель... Так, а где хоть какое либо обновление данных? Я вижу работу с локальной переменной, но где изменение самих данных? Вот допустим вы взяли пирог, создали его копию, покромсали, это отразится на оригинале? Ну значит надо заменить оригинал своей копией, верно? Ну а так, это довольно ужасный код, советую вам как можно быстрее понять почему, ибо потом может быть поздно и трудно от такого отвыкнуть.

Да, это резкий комментарий, но в нём есть намёк на решение и указание на проблему. Это не оскорбление, а попытка дать конструктивный фидбек. Если бы у автора были бы вопросы почему у меня такое мнение, как решить иначе, и так далее, то я, увидев его заинтересованность (ведь обычно подобные вопросы задают на "абы как", лишь получить ответ, скопировать и забыть про программирование в целом), с радостью дал бы развернутый ответ, спросив у человека всю нужную информацию. Тем самым, я бы направил его в нужное направление, которого он уже дальше сам будет придерживаться, ну или вернется обратно к своим наработкам. Главное, что он будет знать, что это не единственный способ решения его задачи!
Тем не менее, комментарий был удалён, и на его месте появился комментарий aepot. Я задал ему вопрос, почему мой комментарий удалён — неужели "ужасный код" это оскорбление? Внятного ответа я так и не получил, только ссылка на "нормы поведения" и удаление всех моих попыток выяснить причину. Одним из комментариев к модератору было такое:

Вот читаем нормы "мы ожидаем от всех участников одинакового относиться к друг другу, с добротой и уважением" - если все одинаковы, то почему вы сейчас унижаете меня? Причем за ерунду по типу "Плохой/ужасный" код. Вы нарушаете мои права, выставляя права других превыше моих. Это разве "одинаково"? Далее... "во время обучения, люди совершают ошибки" - я про эти ошибки и пишу, я про них говорю. Или мы должны замалчивать их? А какой тогда смысл в заведомо неверной информации? "нанести вред" - где вы увидели в "плохой код" вред? Наоборот, человек может поинтересоваться как верно, ему скажут.

Собственно, с каких это пор указание того, что "код ужасен" является "оскорблением?" за которое надо карать и удалять контент (в данном случае комментарий) другого человека? Я лично, считаю это превышением прав данного модератора. Хочется разобраться в этой ситуации и с ним лично, чтобы впредь мой контент не трогали, ибо это уже переходит все рамки...
С таким подходом на SO скоро вообще нельзя будет ничего сказать, будем как роботы следовать четким инструкциям и решать даже в корне неверные задачи, изобретая все новые и новые костыли.
Мой вопрос больше к модераторам, но и мнение сообщества было бы интересно услышать. Считаете ли такие комментарии оскорбительными?

Обсудив в комментариях про "ужасный код" я решил поискать мои комментарии с походим контекстом, и я их нашел.

Тут все +- тоже самое, что в комментарии, цитату которого я привел в вопросе, но... Его не удалили. Скажете "наверно не заметили", но нет, прям после него идет сообщение от aepot, модератора.
Или допустим такой

Тут конечно не совсем тот случай, но я категорически против решения, который автор вопроса хочет реализовать. Комментарий висит, не задевает чьих либо "чувств", его не удаляют.
Или вот

Опять я говорю "Ужасный код", и опять комментарий висит, его не трогают. А автор меня лишь поблагодарил за это и сказал, что задумался о переделки своего кода.
Я могу так продолжать до бесконечности, ибо за 8 лет такого, и даже суровей, накопилось довольно много. Многие наверно слышали "Бить по рукам" - вот тоже одно из выражений, которое гуляет здесь и с ним ничего не делают.
Так ребят (особенно модераторы), за что удаляются мои комментарии? Мне может хоть кто-то внятно объяснить? Разве "ужасный код" является триггером для удаления? Или как вон в комментариях сказали "мы варим мед, а бракованный мед выбрасывают", так что-ли? Ну что за стерильность на взрослом ресурсе, я ведь не в к детям с детский садик пришел, где деток это может расстроить. Ну а если для нас это табу, то давайте тогда пропишем в правилах, что такое запрещено! Ибо "нормы поведения" вообще к этому случаю не подходят.

Upd
Модерация выше всех похвал, браво!
Один шлет на мету, мол "хочешь обсудить, иди!", а другой закрывает вопрос на дубликат того, чем этот вопрос не является. Господа модераторы, я задал конкретный вопрос "Почему ужасный код является поводом для удаления", а не "Почему комментарии удаляются". Они не автоматически удаляются, они не по "стоп слову" удаляются, их удаляет конкретный модератор, вопрос - почему?

я сторонний наблюдатель, но я бы вам советовал убрать оценочные высказывания. Это все. Если вам по темечку будет бить постоянно фраза: "Твой/твое .... ужасен/ужасно", то долго ли продержитесь? вместо точек вставьте что хотите. Я если и считаю, что мне что-то не нравится, я просто покажу по другому, а писать в комментариях, что кто-то плохо написал, ну, зачем?

Я успользую такое: "я бы на вашем месте никогда бы не использовал .... И вот почему...." Крайне воспитано и понятно.

@Dmitry Я в вопросе вроде ясно дал понять зачем это делаю. Сказал бы кто либо мне так в начале моего обучения, я бы не потратил несколько лет в пустую. Да, подобное может быть немного резко, но мы ведь не детский сад, а сообщество взрослых людей, где сказать в лицо куда более действенно и понятней, чем ходить вокруг да около. В любом случае, разве это повод для удаления подобного контента? Как по мне, нет, ибо это не оскорбление, не задевание чувств, не переход на личности, тут нету вообще ничего, что нарушало бы "нормы".

И вот вам тушè: Ваш стиль написания поста ужасен. Бедный ваш учитель по русскому языку, не ужели вы получили положительную оценку за знание этого предмета. Возьмите и перепишите все, что вы тут написали

@Dmitry Без проблем, если ткнут носом и скажут как правильно, с радостью приму во внимание, и если это действительно так, то я дальше решу, стоит мне прислушиваться данных высказываний, или нет. Как я и написал в вопросе, я всегда даю дальнейшее обоснование своих слов, всячески помогая человеку, хоть весь проект напишу за него, показав "как надо". Но тут должно быть желание... Которого часто нету. Ну а я уж извините, не хочу тратить свое время в пустую.

После того, что я указал вам, что вы плохо пишите, стало ли лучше? Я опять вижу этот стиль изложения. И у меня есть время, чтобы вам показать "как надо" писать. Ну, бред же, гиперболизированный. Что вы хотите от сообщества, чтобы вам дали постоянное право оценки чужого кода, примите уже за действительность положение вещей.

@Dmitry "стало ли лучше?" - от части, да. Я немного понял взгляды некоторых людей. "Ну, бред же" - простите, что является "бредом"? То, что в ходе обсуждения в комментариях, которое начинается с "это ужасно" рождается хорошее, верное, качественное решение? Ну ок, бред так бред... "хотите от сообщества" - я написал это в вопросе. Вы кстати, так и не ответили на "В любом случае, разве это повод для удаления подобного контента?", это ключевой вопрос.

Конечено бред, потому что начатое вами обсуждение не приведет к качественному решению. Это будет решение, которое кого-то устраивает, а кого-то нет. Можно ли назвать его качественным? Вообще нет. А про удаление должен отвечать модератор, а не я. Так же как я не оцениваю чужой код, так же я не оцениваю и не несу ответственность за других людей в данном случае за модератора. Я отвечаю только за себя. Я только знаю, что комментарии не предназначены для того чем мы тут с вами занимаеимся. Ну уж и проводить оценку в комментариях, тоже так себе идея. Здесь я на стороне модератора(мнение)

У вас есть инструменты как голос "против", но вы почему то как раз используете более личное общение, чтобы показать, что ТС не прав в чем-то. Зачем вы это делаете? как вас задевает плохо написанный код? у меня такого на несколько терабайт наберется, да и тут на руСО такого полно) В том числе и у меня, я же хуже/лучше не стал. Я вот такой)

@Dmitry Любопытный вы человек) Для вас "Тварь" это "ничего страшного", а вот "Ужасный код" - сразу, как я понял, расстрелять) "отвечает модератор" - который зачастую ошибается и делает поспешные выводы. "Отвечаю только за себя" - а это тут при чем? Когда вы на SO, вы учитесь или учите чему либо других, и в наших с вами интересах делать контент более качественным, показывая как надо, как можно, и так далее. Или вы из тех, кто просто исправит "говнокод" и пойдет дальше? Я вот нет... Любой мой ответ - это мои попытки показать то, как правильно решить конкретную задачу, комментарии не исключение

Я этот вопрос задал для того, чтобы обсудить конкретную ситуацию, где я считаю, что удаление контента (в данном случае комментария) за простое "это ужас" - ну, это слишком. Мы все люди разные, мы все имеем разное воспитание, разные манеры, у всех есть свои "триггеры", которые могут задеть, все мы по разному общаемся. Так может мы будем принимать друг друга такими, какие мы есть, а не унижать права одного в угоду другого? Это из серии "ты" и "вы", кто-то обижается на то, что "без уважение" на "ты" обратились, но это не повод удалять контент с "тыканием", верно? Также и тут.

Ну вот мы и пришли в точку где надо отбиваться и ... Эххх... во-первых, выдирать из контекста про "тварей" не надо. Во-вторых, в вопросе никаких ваших ответов нет (учитель вы мой). В-третьих, про отвечать за себя - это хорошая позиция, которая снимает с меня ответственность за действия других людей. В-четвертых, качественный контент не основан на суждении о качестве кода. И, в-пятых, я рад, что нравлюсь вам как человек

и про последний ваш тезис, также и тут, совсем не так же. Вы собираете с каждой елки по вершку и пытаетесь слепить березу. У вас конкретное возмущение, я дал вам свое видение данной ситуации. И оно отличается от вашего, но ничего критичного. Никто и ничто не пострадало. Уж, контент точно) за который вы так радеете

@Dmitry Отбиваться сейчас заставляете меня вы, начав сразу с нападок. Опять видите, мы разные, по разному воспринимает контент. "Выдираю из контекста" - боже упаси мне это делать. Я увидел однажды конкретное ваше сообщение, где вы прямым текстом сказали "ничего страшного в "Тварь Михайловна" нет", вот я это и привел. Ну а для меня этот ник является оскорбительным. Опять, видите, мы разные. " в вопросе" - а зачем в вопросе мои ответы? Мы сейчас говорим про решения разных задач, где у людей разный подход, одни отвечают на все подряд, а другие пытаются разобраться и написать "как надо".

"качественный контент не основан на суждении о качестве кода" - согласен, но обсуждение  приводит к более качественному решению. Вот вопрос, который я указал, на него можно дать ответ как я называю "от балды" - это будет решение конкретного костыля. А можно обсудить разобраться в теме, обсудить с автором его намерения, а затем написать подробный, развернутый ответ по всем стандартам (с привязками, стилями, нормальным неймингом, и т.д.). Польза какого ответа будет выше для SO и автора? Какой ответ будет качественней?

Люто плюсую (вот и вы @EvgeniyZ, похоже скатываетесь на мою сторону)

Конечно выдрали. Назвать конкретного человека тварью это либо благодать божья (с христианской точки зрения), либо оскорбление (с вашей точки зрения). Как вам мой уход из контекста? оценили?  Вы просто не хотите понять, что вы не охватываете всю ситуацию целиком. Вам не нравится и точка. У меня есть товарищ с именем Адольф. И... барабанная дробь... его имя кого-то оскорбляет. Деревни будем жечь? Анафему объявим?

@avp я чего-то пропустил. Что за сторона? Понял, мы с вами в политоте пару лет назад пересекались)

@Dmitry Что-то вы прям начали жестить... Если я задел, извините. Я лишь обсуждал то, что вы пишете. И понимать, что "не охватываете всю ситуацию целиком" тут походу не желаете вы, ибо вас понесло совсем не туда (по моему мнению, да). Даже если ник взять, вот прям цитата "если ник не оскорбляет напрямую другого человека с указанием на него, то зачем все это?" - вы вдруг не хотите видеть, что "Тварь Михайловна" это оскорбление конкретного отчества человека. Но да ладно, забудем про ники. Я всеж хочу услышать ваше мнение за "ужасен" удалять - это нормально? Просто ваше мнение, не более...

Простите, меня великодушно. Я не могу с вами продолжать беседу. Поскольку вы начинаете оперировать понятием "качественный", но при этом не внесли в это понятие понимание и смысл, то дальше будет полемика, которая не отражает моего видения на вами заданный вопрос. Как пример: качественный вопрос (который вам не нравится) но привлек на руСО 130к просмотров, или качественный вопрос с качественным ответом (который вас нравится) но с 50 просмотрами.

@Dmitry Ну чтож вы так, если не желаете обсуждать, то не стоило и писать комментарии. Удивляться тому, что вам ответит автор конкретного вопроса и хочет это обсудить, это, странно. Ведь ваши изначальные комментарии не из серии "Плюс" или "Минус", а из серии "разжечь спор", ибо вы начинаете с вопроса, хоть и риторического. Ну а в ходе диалога вас  понесло не туда, вы теперь непойми зачем просите от меня качественный контент найти, хотя изначально мы обсуждает "Удалять за "ужасен" это правильно или нет и что в этом оскорбительного?". На вторую часть вы дали пояснение, спасибо, приму во внимание.

я лишь просто показываю вам как можно контекст в свою сторону поворачивать и показывать ситуацию с удобной стороны. Нет, вы меня не задеваете от слова совсем и то что я пишу, вообще не жесть. Почему у вас такое впечатление сложилось? Я же сказал свое мнение, я на стороне модератора конкретно в этом случае. Потому что ваши оценки субъективны. Они имеют право быть? Точно да. Что с ними делать? модератор решил

@Dmitry Хорошо, значит для вас "Ужасный код" - это сразу триггер для удаления. Я вас понял. Спасибо за ваше мнение.

то не стоило и писать комментарии. Жаль что вы не считываете, я просто показываю вам как вашими тезисами легко манипулировать. У вас очень большой вопрос, с оправданиями ваших действий и кучей интересных тезисов, которые можно оспаривать и разводить то, что я делаю. Не сердитесь на меня )

значит для вас "Ужасный код" - это сразу триггер для удаления. Совсем нет. Это ваше суждение. Мне на него все равно

@Dmitry "Жаль что вы не считываете" - Жаль, что вы пытаетесь "манипулировать", разводя тут бесполезный шум. "Совсем нет" - Ну тогда я вас вообще не понимаю. Я поставил конкретный вопрос, на который вы сказали "Я на стороне модератора", а модератор такое сейчас удаляет. То есть вы на стороне тех, кто удаляет контент за то, что там есть простое, не оскорбительное "Ужасный код". Другими словами, вы за удаление такого контента. А сейчас вы говорите "нет". Вас трудно понять...

Не "такое", а конкретно ваш комментарий. Вы не ссылались в вашей теме на подобные случаи с другими. Почему то вы все в одну корзину складываете. Ваш комментарий удален. Один конкретный модератор это сделал, а не модераторы. Будьте уже честны в ваших высказываниях. Не надо говорит то, чего нет. И перечитайте первые 5 моих комментариев, там есть ответы.

@Dmitry Вы хотите, чтобы я по всему SO искал темы и вспоминал что я там писал пару месяцев назад? Вы серьезно? Общий контекст подобных сообщений я написал, их удаляет один модератор, по моему мнению даже по "указанию" конкретного человека в виде тревог с его стороны.  А что вам это даст? Ну вот допустим, я нашел один такой случай, который в сентябре был, вот тема, там комментарий был по типу "Это ужасное решение, где используется async void, нет привязок, и т.д" (не помню, что там точно было. И вот, что вам это даст?

Вот у меня дети приходят и говоря "Папа, а ты знаешь что было?" - При этом понятное дело ожидая мой ответ "Нет" и тогда они продолжают рассказывать, при этом зная, вопроса можно и не задавать, а просто рассказать. Так вот "Ужасный код" без пояснения, в ожидании, что к вам придут и спросят "А что не так, как исправить" - ну детский сад. "Ужасный" или "Милый" код - это чисто субъективное мнение и как мне кажется, многим такие комменты кажутся оскорбительными(хотя бывают тут коды, что по другому и не скажешь). Я считаю, что от таких фраз в комментах лучше воздержаться.

@SwaD Многие комментарии содержат пояснение почему этот код ужасен. Иногда, когда нет места, да, пишу так, как вопросе, если требуется, пишу вторым комментарием. Тут все зависит от изначально заинтересованности автора вопроса. Если я вижу, что он хочет разобраться в теме, пишу более подробно, если нет, там уже захочет, спросит почему и как. Задам и вам тогда вопрос - это разве повод удалять подобное? А если там помимо "Ужасный код" есть еще и куча полезной информации? Вот это вот основное, что я тут хочу понять. Вообще, "детский сад" - это попытка это выяснить во "взрослом" вроде как обществе.

я к тому, что в вопросе одно, в комментариях вы оперируете уже "такое", подразумевая систематичность и предвзятость. Не надо нигде рыскать, не надо мне ничего доказывать. Мне ничего это не дает. Я про конкретную ситуацию, про конкретные действия

@Dmitry "Такое" - это конкретный случай. Чтобы постоянно не писать "комментарий содержащий "Ужасный код"" я пишу "такое" или "подобное". "систематичность" - да, это повторяется неоднократно, поэтому меня это начинает напрягать. Ну а вы меня будто "лжецом" назвали, требуя от меня доказательств, которые я вам выше дал - тема с сообщениями указанного модератора от сентября. Так что поверьте, это не первый случай, и думаю, не последний. Поэтому я и хочу разобраться в этой ситуации, а не читать ваши "манипуляции".

) ну, зачем вы так. Не хотите, не читайте. Но я думал, это вас сподвигнет посмотреть на ситуацию под другим углом. Если бы хотел назвать лжецом, то не сделал бы этого=) Зачем мне это? вы же лучше понимаете, что делаете и для чего вы тут. Удаляюсь)(

Есть производство(ruSO) меда(комменты/ответы). Так вот если в бочку добавить деготь, то это брак, а на производстве брак выкидывают, а не чинят(за редким исключением). Так что если ваш чудо коммент супер прекрасен, но там есть "упреки", то увы... сообщество может поправить вопрос/ответ, а вот коммент нет. Это чисто мое мнение и я им просто делюсь

@SwaD Производства меда и социальная сеть с кучей разных людей со своими взглядами, мнениями, интересами, порядками, и т.д. - это две совершенно разные вещи, где в одной "брак" это неприемлемо, а в другой такой "брак" повсеместно, ибо опять, люди разные. 8 лет мой "брак" народ не смущал, а тут вдруг резко стал неугодным в производстве, ну ну) Но ваше мнение услышал, ок, спасибо.

Оставлю это здесь be nice. Обратите внимание на раздел про комментарии. Заострю ваше внимание на вот это: "...Они в основном рассматриваются как потенциально временные и свободно удаляются, когда больше не нужны..." Не принимайте близко к сердцу

@Dmitry Поймите пожалуйста, я прекрасно знаю что такое комментарии и для чего они нужны на SO. Также я прекрасно понимаю почему они удаляются. Я не понимаю почему "Ужасный код" является триггером к этому действию. Вот что я пытаюсь выяснить. Вот вам понравиться, если вы напишете, ну, не знаю, "погода мерзкая" (чисто пример из головы) в комментария, а вам его удалят без объяснений? А вам не будет потом жалко потраченного времени, например, на изучение вопроса? Мне вот жалко. Сейчас так и вовсе вопрос про "ужасный код" закрыли дубликатом на "почему удаляются комментарии", это разве правильно?

напишите ответ и не используйте комментарии. И не цепляйтесь к словам, вы десять раз везде упоминаете словосочетание "ужасный код". И я вам говорил, что это субъективная оценка. Вы сами указываете, что не все ваши комментарии удаляются с этим словосочетанием, может дело не в этом? это разве правильно?, ну давайте от обратного: а что, не правильно?

@Dmitry Используя тут "Ужасный код" я акцентирую внимание на конкретном комментарии, конкретной проблеме, конкретном случае. Так что, я не "цепляюсь к словам", а лишь акцентирую внимание. "Оценка" - не имеет отношения к поставленному вопросу. Моя оценка, мой комментарий, я написал, удалили - хочу знать почему. Вы опять переходите в длинные споры совершенно на другие темы. Аналогично и с "а что не правильно" - это бесполезный спор, ответ на который я кстати уже дал.

вы спросили я ответил. Как пользователь которому доступна очередь проверки в том числе и вашего переоткрытия, мне не хочется голосовать за это. хочу знать почему, я вам не отвечу, потому что это может сделать только тот кто удалил комментарий, чем он рукводствовался мне не ведомо. Вы говорите постоянно про какой то триггер, но он не срабатывает в других ваших комментариях. Может дело не в нем?

@Dmitry "вы спросили я ответил" - вы не ответили ни на один поставленный вопрос, да и вопросы были риторическими. "мне не хочется голосовать за это" ... "я вам не отвечу"- тогда пожалуйста, пройдите мимо, ибо вы и правда, пишете совсем не по теме. "про какой то триггер" - это после того, как мой вопрос закрыли дубликатом на тему, в которой сказано про автоматическое удаление комментариев, если те содержат "слова триггеры", да и не только...

не злитесь, be nice=) у вас все получится

Здесь просматривается конфликт между принципами открытого обсуждения и необходимостью соблюдать нормы общения. С одной стороны, на техническом ресурсе должны существовать границы конструктивной критики, особенно когда дело касается резких формулировок. С другой стороны, автор справедливо замечает, что его комментарии часто дают полезные подсказки, и в них нет цели кого-либо оскорбить, а стремление помочь и направить новичка к улучшению. Такие советы часто ценятся в технических сообществах, так как новичкам бывает сложно осознать, где и почему их код требует доработки.
В данной ситуации (после внимательного прочтения этого вопроса и приведенных в нем примеров), я полностью на стороне модераторов. Понятие "ужасный код" может восприниматься по-разному. Для одного человека это честный комментарий, а для другого — повод почувствовать себя некомпетентным или даже униженным. Действия модератора могут быть продиктованы желанием сохранить дружелюбный тон на площадке, особенно если в правилах говорится о необходимости уважительного отношения.
Оценочные суждения вроде "ужасный код" не раскрывают суть проблемы. Когда комментарий содержит оценку вроде "ужасный код" или "это в корне неправильно", это может сбивать новичка с толку. Без конкретного объяснения он может воспринять это как общее табу на определённые подходы, а не как указание на проблему в конкретном применении. В результате человек может так и не понять, что именно вызвало критику, или же решит, что так "нельзя писать" вообще, хотя, возможно, подход просто был использован не в том контексте.
Я лично убеждён, что конкретные замечания помогают лучше, чем общие оценки, поскольку позволяют участнику осознать свою ошибку и понять, как избежать её в будущем. Например, вместо "ужасный код" можно было бы указать, что:

В методе Update можно было бы сначала построить все фильтры используя интерфейс IEnumerable<T> и последовательный вызов методов Where, и лишь в конце вызывать ToList один раз. Потому что метод ToList требует обхода всего списка.
Если предполагается сортировка по индексу SelectedIndex, то можно учитывать и вариант убывающей сортировки
Логика фильтрации и сортировки может быть объединена и лучше структурирована
Чтобы обновления данных отражались в ListView, нужно установить ItemsSource для YLV после фильтрации и сортировки.

Точнее, то что автор подразумевал говоря "ужасный код", а не прямо то что я написал выше для примера.
Такое уточнение сразу показывает, в чём именно проблема и как её исправить. Конструктивный фидбек также снижает риск непонимания и недовольства — участник будет чувствовать, что его не осудили, а помогли разобраться.
В долгосрочной перспективе для автора было бы полезно адаптировать стиль, сохраняя полезные замечания, но избегая оценок вроде "ужасный". Вместо этого можно дать конкретный фидбек, указав, какие конкретно аспекты кода требуют доработки и чем это может быть полезно.
Если мы все попробуем сосредоточиться на конкретике, это будет способствовать развитию культуры обучения на площадке.
